# rearrange data in a specific structure

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have data like this format:

| state | year1 | year 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 2000 | 2004-2005 |
| Second | 2007 | 2010-2011 |
| Third | 2008 | 2010 |
| Third | 2010 | 2012 |

I want to make this:

| state | year |
| --- | --- |
| First | 2000 |
| First | 2004-2005 |
| Second | 2007 |
| Second | 2010-2011 |
| Third | 2008 |
| Third | 2010 |
| Third | 2012 |

The code can be in R or Python. Thanks in advance

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% pivot_longer(-state, names_to = "year") %>% select(-name) %>% distinct(state, year)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in the `data.table` package, called `melt( )` which allows you to convert data from wide to long format. In this case I am keeping `State` as my ID variable and the variables I would like pulled into my value field are `Year1` and `Year2`. There is a line that keeps `unique` observations to remove duplicates.

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(
  State = c("First","Second","Third","Third"),
  Year1 = c("2000","2007","2008","2010"),
  Year2 = c("2004-2005","2010-2011","2010","2012"))

data
    State Year1     Year2
1:  First  2000 2004-2005
2: Second  2007 2010-2011
3:  Third  2008      2010
4:  Third  2010      2012

data2 <- melt(
  data = data,
  id.vars = c("State"),
  measure.vars = c("Year1","Year2"),
  variable.name = "Year",
  value.name = "years")

data2 <- unique(data2)

data2[order(State),.(State,years)]
    State     years
1:  First      2000
2:  First 2004-2005
3: Second      2007
4: Second 2010-2011
5:  Third      2008
6:  Third      2010
7:  Third      2010
8:  Third      2012
```